# 256TB, GPT disk, I can, but should I?

Tags: windows, sql-server, storage

I just learned [(thank you Kevh)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/248744/21924) that a GPT drive on Windows  can hold 256TB

> Unlike MBR that limits each partition to only 2TB in size, each partition in GPT can hold up to 2^64 blocks in length (as it is using 64-bit), which is equivalent to 9.44ZB for a 512-byte block (1 ZB is 1 billion terabytes). In Microsoft Windows, that size is limited to 256TB. [Source](https://www.maketecheasier.com/differences-between-mbr-and-gpt/)

Following best practices I use multiple database files based on CPU. On smaller installs, historically I have been putting these on the same MBR drive.  I also use different drives, for tempdb, data files, log files, backups and the OS, so 5 drives minimum for an instance.

Now with GPT I can in theory; put 256TB on a disk, so maybe the days of mounted disks to get past the 26 drive letter limit is gone. (*with MBR and only 26 lettered drives, you are limited to 52TB, without using mounted drives*)

256TB times 26 lettered drives = 6.6ZB

Just because you can doesn't mean you should...

The question:

***What should I consider, when thinking about putting 256TB of datafiles from a SQL instance, on a single lettered disk?***

Comment: I guess you dont use LTO-5 for backup ? Without joking for enterprise use just in example an small enterprise grade SSD can cost like 1k. Can't wait to see how much it would cost to put such big harddisk inside a RAID-6 array in example.

Comment: @yagmoth555 I think we are using RAID-5, I am not in the loop on costs.  Not sure how there would be cost or difference between a single 256TB drive, or thirty two 8TB drives.

Comment: The idea is a single is too much a point of failure bottleneck, you just can't, so in the minimum it would be 2 for raid-1, or 4 for a raid-6 (as raid-5 is classified risky now)

Comment: I might be lost, or I might have not made my question clear.  I am talking about a lettered drive (one of 26) at 256TB on windows server, with RAID-5 behind it.  So if I was presented with E: Drive at 256TB and put my SQL data files on it.  Would that be bad?  Your comments suggest it might not be possible.

Comment: @JamesJenkins: If you have not confirmed how long a recovery would take, it would be bad.

Comment: @GregAskew ah, I see your concern.  As a SQL DBA, I don't care much about the disk recovery time.  The majority of SQL data is in files that are always being written to, so they don't get backuped with the disk contents.  I have to use a special process to make and save backups.  On a typical build, the disk backup only has the 1 or 2 folders with no contents.  If I want to restore, I have to use a separate process unique to SQL.  I might have 10 or 100 backup files stored on tape or another drive that I use.  I would be just as happy with a brand new disk as a restored disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer: NO**, I would not use a single 256 TB NTFS filesystem.

**Long answer:** NTFS is not a pooled filesystem, nor a dataset-based storage system. In other words, the volume encompasses the entire filesystem. This means that specific operations (ie: `chkdsk`, `vssadmin snapshot`, etc) applies to the entire filesystem.

Just imagine how much time a `chkdsk` can take on a nearly full 256 TB NTFS volume: while you can argue that recent NTFS/chkdsk versions can correct an everly-increasing number of issues online (without umounting the volume), *some* problems require an offline scan - during which you can not use the volume or, if it is the system drive, not even boot the OS.

Or think to how a `vssadmin snapshot create`, done to recover a single small file, will commands a massive performance penalty on *all* you SQL databases.

*Side note:* the only filesystem on which I would *consider* using such a big volume (putting aside very proprietary, not "off-the-shell" things as WAFL) is ZFS: being pooled, dataset-based and with a completely online `zfs scrub`, it is by-design suitable for such big storage space. But even with ZFS, at these sizes the option to create multiple pools can not be automatically discarded.

Comment: I think ReFS is now the recommended file system for SQL Server. Could you write some about that?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder frankly, I have read enough stories of troubled ReFS installations that I would not use it for anything mission critical. At least, [this was the common opinion some years ago (2015)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104383/should-i-use-refs-for-a-new-sql-server). That said, I don't have sufficient first hand experience with ReFS to be categoric.

Comment: Yet your answer is very NTFS specific and NTFS isn't even mentioned in the question.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder ReFS has a maximum volume size of 16EB, while NTFS tops at 256 TB, so I thought you were implicitly referring to NTFS. If my assumption was wrong, you can always take my answer it for what it is worth.